# The Feynman Lectures

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation

Page 4-5 of The Feynman Lectures, under the topic of conversation of energy, writes this, while it tries to give a feel about conservation principle.

> > Let us now illustrate the energy principle with a more complicated problem,
> >     the screw jack shown in Fig. 4-5. A handle 20 inches long is used to turn the screw,
> >     which has 10 threads to the inch. We would like to know how much force would
> >     be needed at the handle to lift one ton (2000 pounds). If we want to lift the ton
> >     one inch, say, then we must turn the handle around ten times. When it goes around
> >     once it goes approximately 126 inches. The handle must thus travel 1260 inches,
> >     and if we used various pulleys, etc., we would be lifting our one ton with an unknown smaller weight W applied to the end of the handle. So we find out that W
> >     is about 1.6 pounds. This is a result of the conservation of energy.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to upload the image here, but you can refer to this shortened link (not for commercial purpose) to my drive https://bit.ly/2OZTXLj

Now, what the thing is, I get that when it goes around once, the tip covers approximately 2πl ≈ 126 inches. And that 10 times is 1260 inches, but what I don't get is, how do you go from there (using any arbitrary number of pulley or any other system) to getting W = 1.6 pounds?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: The Feynman lectures are available on-line. Figure 4-5 is on this webpage, https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_04.html

Comment: Here's a direct link to the figure: https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_04.html#Ch4-F5

Answer (score 1):

If you lift one ton one inch the energy you need is $U=mgh$ = 1 ton * $g$ * 1 inch, where of course $g$ is the gravity.
This force has to be balanced by the work $L$ done by the force $F$ pushing the tip and that is $L=$F*1260inches. We can "convert" the force in weight by dividng it by $g$, i.e. $W=F/g$ ($W$ being the weight "equivalent" to the force $F$ in earth's gravitational field...).

By that ($U=L$) we find 1 ton * $g$ * 1 = $F$ *1260 so that $W=F$/$g$=1 ton/1260 which is 1.6 pounds. 
(In a decimal system this would have been much more straightforward, btw)